# How to check the numbers of list label

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a project and it was good before changing in style, but after adding shadow to the #container it gives me this message from the grader:

```
The trading card page has a list of new facts
Each fact should have a corresponding label: expected 4 to equal 8
```

What have I done wrong?

Here is the card.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Building the Prototype</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="container">
        <h1>Panda</h1>
        <!-- photo credit: wikipedia.org, image taken by Ritik -->
        <img src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/18315/images/hero_full/Medium_WW230176.jpg?1576168323" alt="panda">
        <div id="card" class="animal-info">
          <p id="interesting-fact">Pandas live mainly in temperate forests high in the mountains of southwest China, where they subsist almost entirely on bamboo. They must eat around 26 to 84 pounds of it every day, depending on what part of the bamboo they are eating. They use their enlarged wrist bones that function as opposable thumbs.</p>
          <ul id="facts">
            <li>
              <span class="lable">Scientific Name</span>: <span class="value">Ailuropoda melanoleuca</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="lable">Average Length</span>: <span class="value">4 to 5 feet</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="lable">Average Lifespan</span>: <span class="value">20 years</span>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span class="lable">Habitat</span>: <span class="value">Eating in a relaxed sitting posture</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p id="summary">A newborn panda is about the size of a stick of butter—about 1/900th the size of its mother—but females can grow up to about 200 pounds, while males can grow up to about 300 pounds as adults. These bears are excellent tree climbers despite their bulk.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

And here is the styles.css:

```
#container{
    width: 513;
    height: 796;
    object-fit: contain;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 5px #e0e0e0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


#container  img {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding: 1px;
}

#container h1{
    padding: 20px;
}

#card #interesting-fact {
    font-style: italic;
}

.animal-info{
}

#facts .lable {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#facts .value{
    font-style: italic;
}

#card ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#card {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay ..
I had to put the list values without the `<span class="value"></span>` 
That's it :)